# About even and odd question (use recursive)

Tags: javascript

I try to use recursive solve about odd and even question.
When I try call even(3),it return false.
But I don't know why.

```js
let even = function(n) {
    if (n === 0) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return even(n/2);
    }
}
let odd = function(n) {
    if (n === 0) {
        return false;
    }else{
        return odd(n/2);
    }
}

console.log(even(3));
console.log(odd(3));
```

Comment: I just ran your embedded demo, and `console.log(even(3))` is printing `true` for me.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide proof of the *When I try call even(3),it return false* because your code doing well (returning *true*) in the snippet

Comment: `even(x)` returns `true` for any number `x` except for infinity, when it hangs. `odd(x)` returns `false` for any number `x` except infinity, when it hangs.

Answer (score 0):

The `/` operator doesn't do that much for you in JavaScript (unless you're using BigInts), as it will just cut numbers into tinier numbers till there's nothing left. On the other hand, as soon as you employ `%` operator, you don't need recursion any more, since you're done in one step. If you want a recursive solution, this is the obvious one (though horribly inefficient):

```
A number `x` is even is:
  * `true` if it is `0`
  * `true` if `x - 1` is odd
  * `false` otherwise

A number `x` is odd is
  * `false` if it is `0`
  * `true` if `x - 1` is even
  * `false` otherwise
```

(This does not account for negative numbers; if you wish to support them, there's several other checks that need to be made.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not doing what you think. It is continuously dividing by 2 and when it exceeds Javascript's Minimum positive integer, n becomes 0 and whatever is inside your base case is returned. If you want to find if a number is even or not using recursion, you would do something like this:

```
function isEven(n) {
  if (n===0) { // n is even
    return true;
  }
  else if (n===1) { // n is odd
    return false;
  }
  return isEven(n-2);
}
```

Note: This will not work for negative numbers. Maybe you can call this recursive function inside a helper function that will turn it into a positive number first.